# Recursive function definition in coq with limit on set of possible inputs

Tags: coq

I need to define a recursive function with no easily measurable argument.  I keep a list of used arguments to ensure that each one is used at most once, and the input space is finite.

Using a measure `(inpspacesize - (length l))` works mostly, but I get stuck in one case.  It seems I'm missing the information that previous layers of `l` have been constructed correctly, i. e. there are no duplicates and all entries are really from the input space.

Now I'm searching for a list replacement that does what I need.

**Edit** I've reduced this to the following now:

I have `nat`s smaller than a given `max` and need to ensure that the function is called at most once for every number.  I've come up with the following:

```
(* the condition imposed *)
Inductive limited_unique_list (max : nat) : list nat -> Prop :=
  | LUNil  : limited_unique_list max nil
  | LUCons : forall x xs, limited_unique_list max xs
             -> x <= max
             -> ~ (In x xs)
             -> limited_unique_list max (x :: xs).

(* same as function *)
Fixpoint is_lulist (max : nat) (xs0 : list nat) : bool :=
  match xs0 with
  | nil     => true
  | (x::xs) => if (existsb (beq_nat x) xs) || negb (leb x max)
                 then false
                 else is_lulist max xs
  end.

(* really equivalent *)
Theorem is_lulist_iff_limited_unique_list : forall (max:nat) (xs0 : list nat),
    true = is_lulist max xs0 <-> limited_unique_list max xs0.
Proof. ... Qed.

(* used in the recursive function's step *)
Definition lucons {max : nat} (x : nat) (xs : list nat) : option (list nat) :=
  if is_lulist max (x::xs)
    then Some (x :: xs)
    else None.

(* equivalent to constructor *)
Theorem lucons_iff_LUCons : forall max x xs, limited_unique_list max xs ->
    (@lucons max x xs = Some (x :: xs) <-> limited_unique_list max (x::xs)).
Proof. ... Qed.

(* unfolding one step *)
Theorem lucons_step : forall max x xs v, @lucons max x xs = v ->
  (v = Some (x :: xs) /\ x <= max /\ ~ (In x xs)) \/ (v = None).
Proof. ... Qed.

(* upper limit *)
Theorem lucons_toobig : forall max x xs, max < x
    -> ~ limited_unique_list max (x::xs).
Proof. ... Qed.

(* for induction: increasing max is ok *)
Theorem limited_unique_list_increasemax : forall max xs,
  limited_unique_list max xs -> limited_unique_list (S max) xs.
Proof. ... Qed.
```

I keep getting stuck when trying to prove inductively that I cannot insert an element into the full list (either the IH comes out unusable or I can't find the information I need).  As I think this non-insertability is crucial for showing termination, I've still not found a working solution.

Any suggestions on how to prove this differently, or on restructuring the above?

Comment: Without specifics, in particular on the domain of your function, it's hard to help. Apparently, the domain can be enumerated in a finite list, but it has to verify a property - itself recursive, and contain no duplicate elements, is that it ? Would you mind giving us more indications on that, perhaps some of the code and definitions you have already ? Without them, it's hard to do more than recommend section 15 of the [Coq'Art](http://www.amazon.com/Interactive-Theorem-Proving-Program-Development/dp/3642058809/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1309845806&sr=8-1).

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say much without more details (please elaborate!), but:

- Are you using the [Program](http://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual028.html) command? It's certainly very helpful for defining functions with non-trivial measures.
- For uniqueness wouldn't it work if you tried sets? I remember writing ones a function that sounds very much like what you are saying: I had a function for which an argument contained a set of items. This set of items was growing monotonously and was limited to a finite space of items, giving the termination argument.

Comment: Yes, I'm using `Program Fixpoint`.  I did look at set and did not know how to use it, but I've simplified my problem to `nat`s with an upper limit now, so maybe it'll work.  I'll look at that again.

Comment: If you're still stucked try providing some more details here.